# need to check if gps is enabled or not

Tags: java, android, android-gps

i am making a app in which on click of button it moves from 1 activity to 2nd activity on which i need gps to be active i used a alertdialog box to turn on the gps by clicking settings it will open to the setting and if i enable it dialogbox disapper and gps start working but if i press back button without enabling the gps it works and activity starts i want to check if gps is enabled if not the it should not show me the 2nd activity

No Error Coming but just on back press on setting without enabling it will start activity without any error and still gps is off.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
    textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location_view);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.camera);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload);
    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.remarks);
    imageView11 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);


    locationText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location_view);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat
            .checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission
                .ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 101);
    }

    getLocation();
}



public void getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 5, (LocationListener) this);
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.item1:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Account Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
         case R.id.item2:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Account Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
         case R.id.item3:

             AlertDialog.Builder alerDialogbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main3Activity.this);
             alerDialogbuilder.setTitle("Confirm Logout");
             alerDialogbuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_error_black_24dp);
             alerDialogbuilder.setMessage("Are You Sure You Want to Logout ");
             alerDialogbuilder.setMessage("Logingout will need id password again");
             alerDialogbuilder.setCancelable(false);
             alerDialogbuilder.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                     Intent intents = new Intent(Main3Activity.this,MainActivity.class);
                     startActivity(intents);
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Successfull Logout",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                         }
             });
             alerDialogbuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Logout Canceled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
             });
             AlertDialog alertDialog = alerDialogbuilder.create();
             alertDialog.show();


            return true;
           default:return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    }

private void camera(){
    Intent intents = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intents,CAMERA_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST&&resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){
        Bitmap photo= (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView11.setImageBitmap(photo);

    }
}

private void upload(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alerDialogbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main3Activity.this);
    alerDialogbuilder.setTitle("Confirm Upload ?");
    alerDialogbuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_error_black_24dp);
    alerDialogbuilder.setMessage("Are You Sure You Want to Upload Data");
    alerDialogbuilder.setCancelable(false);
    alerDialogbuilder.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File Uploading...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    alerDialogbuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Recheck Data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alerDialogbuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    if(view==button1){
        camera();
    }

    else if (view == button2){
        upload();
    }

}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    double lati = location.getLatitude();
    double longi = location.getLongitude();

    locationText.setText("Latitude: " + lati + "\n Longitude: " + longi);

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enable GPS and Internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alerDialogbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main3Activity.this);
    alerDialogbuilder.setTitle("Enable Gps to Continue");
    alerDialogbuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_error_black_24dp);
    alerDialogbuilder.setMessage("If You Want To Enable Gps Go To Settings");
    alerDialogbuilder.setCancelable(false);
    alerDialogbuilder.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent1);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enable Gps..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    alerDialogbuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            finish();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Uploading Failed,Enable Gps",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alerDialogbuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
    }
  }
```

i want to check only if gps is enabled or not when my activity start if it is not enabled go to settings and still if the user doesnot enable the gps setting it should not work any further pls help me out m a new to android

Comment: Please Provide me a working ans to update or change code in which class please

Answer (score 2):

Implement below method for checking status -:

```
public boolean CheckGpsStatus() {

         LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

         boolean GpsStatus = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            return GpsStatus;
        }
```

Comment: where to implement ??

Comment: pls check my code and help me out i will be very thankful to you

Comment: call this method in onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState ) method in a if condition statement,  if it's true then get location otherwise finish activity or you can ask permission again or go to gps setting page dynamically.

Comment: @DaRkwArRiOr check my answer it will guide you how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected LocationRequest locationRequest;



public void checkForLocationRequest() {
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setInterval(MIN_UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        locationRequest.setNumUpdates(1);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
//        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    }
    public void checkForLocationSettings() {
        try {
            LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
            builder.addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
            SettingsClient settingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(MainActivity.this);
            settingsClient.checkLocationSettings(builder.build())
                    .addOnSuccessListener((Activity) MainActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
//                            delay(1);
                            //Setting is success...
                            //  Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "Enabled the Location successfully. Now you can press the buttons..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener((Activity) MainActivity.this, new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            int statusCode = ((ApiException) e).getStatusCode();
                            switch (statusCode) {
                                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                                    try {
                                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(), and check the
                                        // result in onActivityResult().

                                        ResolvableApiException rae = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                                        rae.startResolutionForResult((Activity) MainActivity.this, GET_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE);
                                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                                        new MyUtils().catchError(MainActivity.this, ex);
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Setting change is not available.Try in another device.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            new MyUtils().catchError(MainActivity.this, e);

        }
    }
```

This Above code shows the popup for enable the gps if gps is not enabled and also gives you callback for success and failure

Comment: okie this are the two methods uh have defined seperatly i have to used this where i want to check it right??

Comment: Worked for me but Sir  i updated the code with backpressed() command in Onstatus changed  now its working but whene ever i press back button its working that means backbutton without enabling gps it open back activity but when i enable gps then we press back button it again come back to the previous activity

Answer (score 0):

```
        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
                implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener ,OnMapReadyCallback,LocationListener{

     protected static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
        protected static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;

        Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
        GoogleMap mgooglemap;
        private LocationManager locationManager;


@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        //Place current location marker
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
      //  MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
      //  markerOptions.position(latLng);
      //  markerOptions.title("Current Position");
       // markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
      // mCurrLocationMarker = mgooglemap.addMarker(markerOptions);


        //move map camera
        mgooglemap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,16));
mgooglemap.getMaxZoomLevel();
      //  locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enable GPS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

//for you want to open Settings screen
while(!onProviderEnabled())
{
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
}

    }
```

The **onProviderDisabled()** of the above code will provide you the required flow.

Comment: but it will only toast a text to enable gps.but i want to show gps setting in settings and then uh cant go back with back button without enabling gps i want this sir

Comment: i got the code sir but what if i open activity and without enabling my gps click on back button my activity starts without gps

Comment: i donot want any update in my program just need a code to check if gps is enabled or not if not it does move to next location

Comment: what is next location?

Comment: Check the updated answer. Thats the most possible way to get the desired solution

Comment: sir in on provider disabled 
it will open setting if i dnt enable it and press back button it will come to the main screen but if we enable it it still come to main activity instead of remain on the same Activity

Comment: Your situation is :
1. if gps disabled -> Open Settings -> turned ON -> MainActivity.
2. if gps enabled -> MainActivity.
is it so???

Comment: i just want that my app should check if gps is enabled or not if its enabled then remain on same activity otherwise it should come back to previous activity untill it is enabled

Comment: sir i just need to check if my gps i currently active or not if active continue if not the it will not work or to any activity untill gps is enabled and recheckd

Comment: in short if not enabled GPS -> Go back to previous activity ?? is it right?

Comment: 1. if gps disabled -> Open Settings -> turned ON -> MainActivity. if still its disabled if person come back to activity without enabling it it should not work further 2. if gps enabled -> MainActivity. is it so???

Comment: sir i only need check code to check if my gps is enabled if not stay on the same activity i am using onpost resume command in which it checks for gps enabled or disabled if disabled it will not work and if enabled on resume stops and my other works starts